# In extjs how to generate app.js in remote server while running sencha command

Tags: extjs

I want to place app.js in my S3 bucket and access it through Cdn Url.So what changes I have to done in my app.json file or any other property file before running sencha Command.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/extjs/cmd_app.html
https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_build.html

You might want to modify the build scripts under:

```
.sencha/app/build-impl.xml          # Standard application build script
```

You need to create an ant task to copy the files to s3. 
Check this repo:

https://github.com/corley/aws-ant-task

Comment: Suppose if I run the generate app by using  sencha command and  then manually place  app.js file in s3 bucket then in which file I have to make a change such that the application points to app.js file that I have kept in s3 bucket not to my server's app.js file.

Comment: Please excuse me, i dont get what you want. As far as i understand you, you wanna run "sencha app build" and copy the created artifacts under /build/production/appname to your s3 bucket, right? And then you wanna change the reference to your remote file? For that i guess you have to change the microloader config which handles the loading part. https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/microloader.html Or you can simply include the file using standard script tag in your index.html. I hope i got you right.

Comment: Actually I just want to put my js files on s3 bucket  which is app.js in which all  js code resides . All other files will remain on my server only..

Comment: Ah, ok - take a look on the repo page and scroll down to a simple s3 task. This should be added to your build-impl.xml.

Comment: When I build app for testing environment by command "sencha app build testing" then in the index.jsp page I see app.js entry but when I run "sencha app build" that is build for production environment then in index.jsp page there is no entry of app.js . So can u tell from where it reads app.js in runtime

Comment: This depends on your config, but in general in extjs6, afaik, it will generate the artifacts under /build/production/{appname}/...

Comment: Now suppose when I create build for testing environment by CDN Url is different then that of Uat and Production.So can u tell the best way how I can handle build Processing in the efficient way.. For now, when I create war File of application before deploying I have to manually change the path of app.js in app.json and replace it with the cloudfront Url of either Test environment ,Uat environment  or Production environment.

Comment: yes, you can define build types / flavours in the app.json. take a look under js and output here: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/microloader.html